# How to run SQL query group by issue?

Tags: oracle

I have a table with columns :

Table Name: IdentityTable

```
ID         Dest_Name       Dest_Reference_Id         Format        IG

31231231    India               Delhi                XKHYGUI       21    
12313131    USA                 Washington           XHKOWKG       1    
34645542    India               Mumbai               XKLWOFH       1   
31231314    USA                 California           XLGJDJG       21   
31234531    India               Delhi                XKHIHUI       21    
12375671    USA                 Washington           XHKLHKG       21   
12574613    USA                 Washington           XLKWMKG       1
```

and so on...

I want to query this table to retrieve information in this form:

```
Dest_Name  Dest_Reference_Id   Total_Format     Format            IG

India         Delhi                2            XKHYGUI           21
India         Delhi                2            XKHIHUI           21    
USA           Washington           3            XHKOWKG           1   
USA           Washington           3            XHKLHKG           21  
USA           Washington           3            XLKWMKG           1    
India         Mumbai               1            XKLWOFH           1   
USA           California           1            XLGJDJG           21
```

I did:

```
select dest_name, dest_reference_id, count (format)
from IdentityTable
Group By dest_name, dest_reference_id;
```

I could retrieve all information required except Format column in the result. How should I modify my query to return expected result ?

Comment: Are you using mysql or oracle?  They are different DBMS's, please tag only one as your answer may depend on syntax based on the platform.

Comment: My bad. I am Using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Make two sub-queries and join em up.

```
SELECT counts.dest_name, 
       counts.dest_reference_id,
       counts.total_format,
       idents.format,
       idents.IG
FROM
(
  select dest_name, dest_reference_id, count (format) as total_format
  from IdentityTable
  Group By dest_name, dest_reference_id;
) counts
join
(
  select distinct dest_name, dest_reference_id, format, IG
  from identitytable 
) idents
on    counts.dest_name = idents.dest_name
  and counts.dest_reference_id = idents.dest_reference_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count(*) over(partition by dest_name, dest_reference_id)
```

and without a `group by`. google "oracle analytic functions".